# Symfony 3.4 Entity Relation Many to Many

Tags: symfony, many-to-many, entity

I want to associate the relation ManytoMany between two entites Users and Menu.
So i did the code below the entity users:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Menu")
 */
private $menus;
```

and the code below on the entity menu:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Users")
 */
private $userss;
```

But the result is two transtive tables when i update my schemea:users_menu and menu_users.
It should be just one , why two and how can i fix it.
NB: I m using the version 3.4.

Comment: If I had to guess I would suspect the extra s's might be the cause.  $userss.  At a minimum you might do yourself a favor and call your User entity User.  And consider dropping your current schema and creating a new one.

Comment: I change the code of entity users:/**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Menu")
     */
    private $menu;                                                                                                        and the code of menu entity:/**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Users")
     */
    private $users;                                                                                                          but it still generating two tables

Comment: have a look at the `mappedBy` and `inversedBy` attributes, which is mentioned in https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-bidirectional

Comment: It s ok after adding  the options  the mappedBy and inversedBy

Answer (score 0):

It is important to understand the concept of the owning and inverse sides

Here is doc: [Association: Owning Side and Inverse Side](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/unitofwork-associations.html#association-updates-owning-side-and-inverse-side)

There are two types of relationships you can do.

1.[Many-To-Many, Unidirectional](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-unidirectional)

2.[Many-To-Many, Bidirectional](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-bidirectional)

In your case let say user is owing side(unidirectional).

```
 /**
 * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Menu")
 * @JoinTable(name="users_menus",
 *      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="menu_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 */

private $menus;
```

**Important:** Doctrine will only check the owning side of an association for changes.